# Generic vs Any function in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, generics, any

What is the difference between

```
inline fun <reified T> T.TAG(): String = T::class.java.simpleName
```

and

```
fun Any.TAG(): String = this::class.java.simpleName
```

is there any difference between using generic and Any as function parameter or as extended function class name?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a difference.

```
inline fun <reified T> T.TAG1(): String = T::class.java.simpleName
fun Any.TAG2(): String = this::class.java.simpleName
```

`TAG1` would get the *compile-time* type as the type of `T` is determined at compile time, and `TAG2` would get the runtime type. `this::class` is similar to `this.getClass()` in Java.

For example:

```
val x: Any = "Foo"
```

`x.TAG1()` would give you `Any::class.java.simpleName`, and `x.TAG2()` would give you `String::class.java.simpleName`.

Comment: a few more examples: `listOf<Int>()` will give `List` and `EmptyList`. `listOf<Int>(1)` will give `List` and `SingletonList`.  `listOf<Int>(1, 2)` will give `List` and `ArrayList`.

Comment: does it mean using generic is always better than using Any?

Comment: @Jooo21 Well, depends on what you want, really. If you want the compile time type, then sure, using generics will get you that.